# Angular service worker - app doesn't load when installed on mobile

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have an Angular project with a Service Worker. If I open the app in a browser (on desktop or on mobile), I don't have a problem but if I install the application on a mobile phone, I see the spinner and the application doesn't load.

Version:

```
    Angular CLI: 9.0.5
    Node: 10.13.0
    @angular-devkit/architect          0.900.5
    @angular-devkit/build-angular      0.900.5
    @angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.900.5
    @angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.900.5
    @angular-devkit/core               9.0.5
    @angular-devkit/schematics         9.0.5
    @angular/cdk                       9.1.1
    @angular/flex-layout               9.0.0-beta.29
    @angular/material                  9.1.1
    @angular/material-moment-adapter   9.2.0
    @ngtools/webpack                   9.0.5
    @schematics/angular                9.0.5
    @schematics/update                 0.900.5
    rxjs                               6.5.4
    typescript                         3.7.5
    webpack                            4.41.2
```

Comment: Are you using `@angular/service-worker` or you have written your own custom service worker JS file? Also can you share your SW if that's the case.

Comment: I user @angular/service-worker

Comment: Can you show us how do you register the service worker and what is your ngsw-config.json?

Comment: I have not registered the service worker but it's running, I add the ngsw-config.json

Comment: And If I put offline in Google, the application works well

Answer (score 0):

The ngsw-config.json

```
    {
     "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service- 
      worker/config/schema.json",
      "index": "/test/test/index.html",
      "assetGroups": [
       {
        "name": "app",
        "installMode": "prefetch",
        "resources": {
        "files": [
            "/test/test/favicon.ico",
            "/test/test/index.html",
            "/test/test/manifest.webmanifest",
            "/test/test/*.css",
            "/test/test/*.js"
        ],
        "urls": [
              "https://test.com/test/test/upload/**",
              "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
              family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap",
              "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
        ]
       }
        }, {
         "name": "assets",
         "installMode": "lazy",
         "updateMode": "prefetch",
         "resources": {
          "files": [
           "/test/test/assets/**",
           "/test/test/*.
          (eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
         ]
        }
       }
     ],
     "dataGroups": [
       {
        "name": "test-api",
        "urls": [
         "https://test.com/test/api/**"
        ],
        "cacheConfig": {
        "maxSize": 20,
        "maxAge": "30d",
        "timeout": "5s",
        "strategy": "freshness"
       }
      }
     ]
    }
```